# Error using \tikzexternalize with forest

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external, forest

Using `forest` package for simple truth trees, and I want to externalize because there are a lot of them. Here is the code example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[external]{forest}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    [$B \rightarrow C$
        [$C$
            [$\neg A$
                [$\neg B$
                ]
                [$C$
                ]
            ]
            [$B$
                [$\neg B$
                ]
                [$C$
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Here is the error:

```
Command Line:   texify.exe --src --tex-option=--interaction=errorstopmode
--tex-option=--synctex=-1

.....    

ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros forest: Invoking a recursive call to
generate the external picture 'Test2-fores t-1' for the following
context+code: 'dj,8.39996pt,0.4pt,.3333em,.5\pgflinewidt h
,.3333em,.5\pgflinewidth @@ [$B \rightarrow C$ [$C$ [$\neg A$ [$\neg B$ ] [$C
$ ] ] [$B$ [$\neg B$ ] [$C$ ] ] ] ] ' ! Undefined control sequence.
\forest@temp ->\path
                     [draw](node@2.parent anchor)--(node@3.child anchor);
l.24 \end{forest}

? x No pages of output. Transcript written on Test2.log. texify: latex failed
for some reason (see log file).
```

Everything works fine if I comment out `\tikzexternalize`.

Comment: This looks like a major bug. It seems that the `forest` environment doesn’t include the `tikzpicture` environment correctly when externalizing. (`forest` also presets the command to copy files to `cp` which does not work (at least on Windows).) It might be best to notify the author, see the [package documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/forest/forest.pdf) for contact information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed a bug, thanks for finding it!

I have introduced the bug in v1.03 while introducing keys `begin draw` and `end draw`. (The idea behind the keys is to be able to customize the `tikzpicture` environment used throughout the document, or even use something else than `tikz` to draw the tree.)

The bug arose because the previous `\tikz` command was replaced by a pair of `\pgfkeysalso{/forest/begin draw}` and `\pgfkeysalso{/forest/end draw}` defaulting to `\begin{tikzpicture}` and `\end{tikzpicture}`. While processing the expansion of `\begin{tikzpicture}`, `tikz`'s externalization macros were searching for `\end{tikzpicture}` to collect the picture environment. However, `\end{tikzpicture}` was hidden in the expansion of `\pgfkeysalso{/forest/end draw}` and could thus not be found. I have corrected this by expanding the keys in advance. (I have also fixed another bug I found along the way, in `\forest@externalizing@maybeoptimize`.)

The corrected version can be temporarily found [here](http://spj.ff.uni-lj.si/tiki-download_wiki_attachment.php?attId=304&page=Sa%C5%A1o%20%C5%BDivanovi%C4%87). Please let me know if it works. If it does, I'll post a new version to CTAN asap.

A side note on `pgf`/`tikz`'s externalization mechanism. While I found it extremely handy in general, I needed to hack into it to use it in `forest` and the resulting code seems like black magic. (I shudder to think what adjustments will be necessary with the new version of `pgf`/`tikz`.) While working on the issue, I had some ideas on how to make it easier to use for package writers (also for packages that do not use `pgf`/`tikz`) and, most importantly, how to make it radically faster using multi-page PDFs. So, a question: is there interest for such a new version?

Comment: That definitely worked.

Comment: Just wondering if you could say whether this should currently work with TeX Live 2015 and the current version of `forest`. I've tried with both 1.07 and 1.03 (from your link) and get errors in both cases. (Adding `etex` for the 1.03 version, of course.) On the other hand, this has *never* worked for me, so maybe I am the bug.  But see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254590/tikz-externalize-fails-with-forest).

Answer (score 2):

I agree that this looks like a bug.
As @Qrrbrbirlbel mentioned, the `tikzpicture` environment is not being set up correctly when using the `external` option, and therefore the compiler fails to recognize tikz commands, such as `\path`.

I managed to compile the example by changing the following lines in the `forest` package code:

```
%% Old 
\pgfkeysalso{/forest/begin draw}%
...
\pgfkeysalso{/forest/end draw}%
```

to

```
%% New 
\begin{tikzpicture}
...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Perhaps someone can help with understanding why this error arises only when the `external` option is set, and propose a better solution.

Here is a different version that works.
(Note: this needs to be compiled using: `pdflatex -shell-escape file.tex`.)

[Download forest2.sty](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/85c63d9619476896765f)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[external]{forest2}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    [$B \rightarrow C$
        [$C$
            [$\neg A$
                [$\neg B$
                ]
                [$C$
                ]
            ]
            [$B$
                [$\neg B$
                ]
                [$C$
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```