# TikZ externalize fails with Forest

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external, forest

I'm having a hard time getting TikZ externalize and Forest to play nicely. Here is a MWE (`text.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[external]{forest} 
\tikzexternalize
\tikzset{
  external/system call={
    xelatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=nonstopmode -jobname 
    "\image" "\texsource"
  }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  [a
    [b]
    [c]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

I compile by invoking `latexmk -xelatex -pvc test.tex --shell-escape`. The first time, everything works: I get a pdf output, and the tree is externalized as its own pdf. However, all subsequent compiles fail, with the following error:

```
! Argument of \tikzexternal@externalizefig@systemcall@uptodatecheck has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.17 \end{forest}

?
```

I'm using xelatex, but an identical error is present with a pdflatex compile.

The issue seems to be due to the interaction of Forest and TikZ: replacing the forest environment in the MWE with a tikzpicture environment fails to reproduce the error.

I'm using MacTeX-2015 and pgf version 3.0.0, along with the latest version of Forest (so says tlmgr). Thanks for any help you can offer.

## EDIT (Addition by cfr)

I can reproduce the problem with the following minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[external]{forest}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [a[b][c]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

with `pdflatex --shell-escape` on GNU/Linux with TeX Live 2015 updated a couple of hours ago.

The error on second compilation is:

```
(./prawf3.for)
! Argument of \tikzexternal@externalizefig@systemcall@uptodatecheck has an extr
a }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.13 \end{forest}
```

Gonzalo Medina can reproduce this.

Comment: Welcome! I use `forest` and externalisation with TikZ extensively. I have never once successfully externalised a `forest`. I'm not saying it can't be done - clearly it is possible - but I decided it was not worth further energy trying to resolve the issues and just switch externalisation off for `forest` environments. Note that I get multiple errors even if I don't run with shell escape so that it falls back to non-externalisation.

Comment: Thanks! The recent [`forest` user manual](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/forest/forest.pdf) suggests that it is possible (p.20), as you say, and prior threads on here indicate that it worked in principle, at least once upon a time ([e.g.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138986/error-using-tikzexternalize-with-forest)). Seems like a bug or incompatibility was introduced somewhere along the way, perhaps relatively recently.

Comment: You are ignoring the more obvious possibility that I just don't get it. But, yes, I've seen people say it works... or once worked... or should work. But, as you say, the simplest possible document seems to fail, so I'm not sure what their trick is!

Comment: I just downloaded version 1.03 from the link provided in the answer you linked to. If I use that rather than the current version, it still fails even if I add `\usepackage{etex}` (which is necessary to work around an incompatibility between current TL and previous versions of forest). So I'm not sure that it can be that the bug has been reintroduced.... Unless my brain is the buggy bit.

Comment: I've abused the comments system to leave a couple of messages for people, including the package author. Maybe somebody will bite ;).

Comment: I hope you will not mind that I have added a couple of further data points to your question. (You can roll back my edit if you object.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error is due to an internal change in `pgf`.

Can you confirm that adding the following code to the preamble solves your problem. If it does, I'll post a new version of `forest` on ctan.

```
\makeatletter
\def\forest@includeexternal@check#1{%
  \tikzsetnextfilename{#1}%
  \IfFileExists{\tikzexternal@filenameprefix/#1}{\tikzexternal@file@isuptodatetrue}{\tikzexternal@file@isuptodatefalse}%
}
\makeatother
```

Apology #1: I know it's bad practice to rely on the internals of other packages, but there was no other way I could make externalization work ...

Apology #2: I have had this fix included in a new version of `forest` I'm preparing, but forgot to include it in the patches of the old version.

Comment: Thank you, that worked like a charm! Compiling, and super-speedily now. Appreciate the quick reply, and all your hard work on `forest`.

Comment: Just posted the patched version to ctan.

Comment: Appreciate this and looking forward to beta testing the new version when you're ready!